# How to add a hyperlink to an action button?

Tags: openoffice.org

How to add a hyper-link to an action button in Open Office.org Presentation?

Answer (score 1):

This is  from Oracle's [OpenOffice Help TNT blog](http://blogs.sun.com/oootnt/entry/exploring_hidden_secrets_push_buttons):

> - Right-click the new push button and    choose Control from the context menu.
>   This opens one of the two main
>   properties windows.
> - Right click the Action list button    and select "Open document/web page"
>   from the list.
> - The URL text field is now enabled.    Click the […] button next to the URL
>   text field to select the document
>   that should be opened when a user
>   clicks the button.

The last step here is applicable only if you want to link to a document. If you want to link to a web page, enter the url in the "URL" field, right below where you selected the action.

Now you've got to leave design mode (button in the form controls toolbar) for the button to work.

Comment: Were do I find new push buttons? Is there a way I could attach a hyper-link to basic shape or symbol shape buttons?

Comment: Please ask only one question here; *Ask your other question seperately*. If you feel this has answered your original question, please mark it by clicking the green check mark on the left.

Comment: The link is broken as http://blogs.sun.com is no more. changing it to https://blogs.oracle.com doesn't fix it either.